# Recall a Function at Itself "if statement"

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am working in some exercise with Jquery that allows me to reorder some elements. The example I take to explain it here is based on the number inside some `<li>` tags like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  .
  .
</ul>
```

Here I want to reorder and I think about some logic with this function, for each `li` element remove it and place it at the bottom.

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().append(this);
    reorder ($(this));
})
```

Then with this another function evaluate the value of the previous element<sub>var prev</sub> and if `prev` is lower then place the element above that one.

```
function reorder(p) {
    var val = parseInt(p.text()),
        prev = parseInt(p.prev().text());
    if (val > prev) {
        p.prev().before(p);
    } 
}
```

Now the question is I need if the statement is true reevaluate the values with the new `prev` element to consider the new position. Some this way:

```
 if (val > prev) {
    p.prev().before(p);
    // And Run again the function to compare with the new prev element
 }
```

Can someone show me the way to do this?

Here is a [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/64HXL/)

---

Pd: I now there are other options like [This](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/) to get the reorder but the example goes more about the recall of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call it again (this is known as [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)):

```
if (val > prev) {
    p.prev().before(p);
    reorder (p);
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/64HXL/1/)

Comment: Thanks I read some about it but don't know how to make the call.